# Series ( Should I use AST or CT?)

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty  \frac{(-1)^{n+1}+n^2}{n^3+1}$$

So this is another series qustion that I have encountered during my HW and I have two ways of solving it in my mind. I could split the series into $\sum_{n=1}^\infty  \frac{n^2}{n^3+1}$ and $\sum_{n=1}^\infty  -\frac{(-1)^n}{n^3+1}$ but as you can probably see finding the limit for the second series is extremely difficult.

So a better way to solve this according to my notes would be to use the alternating series but I cannot get this series in the form $(-1)^{n+1} {b_n}$

Any help?

Comment: Use comparison test and find a lower bound for the summand.

Comment: What do you mean by solving it?  Do you want to test convergence or find its value?  In the split that you wrote down, the second sum is alternating, it's the first one that's hard to deal with.

Answer (score 1):

$$\frac{n^2+(-1)^{n+1}}{n^3+1}\geq \frac{n^2-1}{n^3+1}> \frac{1}{2 n}$$ As the last series diverges, it diverges the given one, too.

Comment: Could you elaborate please because I don't understand how you got $\frac{n^2-1}{n^3+1}$

Comment: When $n$ is even the general term is $\frac{n^2-1}{n^3+1}$ @CaporalFourrier